# Fire event after component is built

Tags: jquery, json, jqtree

I'm using [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/) in a project in this way:

1. dynamically add 'p' elements with '.root' class to the page.
2. when a button is clicked, call jqTree for each of the 'p.root'
   elements.
3. after each li is added, add an id using the onCreateLi event
   handler.
4. after all trees are created, add a class to highlight the li's that
   occur more than once.

The last step is where I'm having trouble.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
        $('#compare-button').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var last = false;
            $('#output p.root').each(function(){
                if ($(this).is(':last-child'))
                { last = true; } // set last = true on the last p.root
                $(this).tree({
                    dataUrl: 'http://path/to/service/',
                    autoOpen: true,
                    dragAndDrop: false,
                    onCreateLi: function(node, $li){
                        $li.attr("value", node.id);

                        if (total_count.hasOwnProperty(node.id)) {  total_count[node.id]++; }
                        else {  total_count[node.id] = 1; }

                        if (last && $li.is(':last-child')) // Once we're done with our calls to .tree(), fire the highlighting code.
                        {
                            $.each(total_count, function(key, value){
                                if (value > 1) { $('li[value="' + key +'"] span').addClass('highlight'); }
                            });
                        }
                    } // end of onCreateLi
                }) // end of tree() 
            }); // end of each()                
        }); // end of click()
```

The problem is that the 'onCreateLi' fires after each li, so the one it just created will *always* be the last sibling.  I also tried a .load() on the end of the .each(), but it seemed to interrupt the building of the tree (I'm guessing it gets fired before the trees are built).

This would be much easier if there was a .afterLoad() event handler for jqTree.

EDIT: Wait, this might actually be working...

EDIT 2: Works in Firefox, not in IE.

EDIT 3: I'm going to ask this a different way, so more jQuery experts that aren't familiar with jqTree can answer it.  I'm looping over each of the 'p.root' elemets using jQuery.each().  After that loop is done, I need to fire some code.  I tried jQuery.each().after(), but it seems to interrupt the building of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the [tree.init](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#event-tree-init) event. The event is called after the tree is loaded and rendered.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but the docs say that it's when the tree is 'initialized', so I took that as when it's first called, not when it's complete.

Comment: Nope.  tree.init fires as soon as the tree is initiated.  No dice.